# Create a screenshot of a WPF control in a background thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

we need to create WPF controls (say, a canvas with some Images on it) in a background thread and then take a screenshot of them. The controls must not be displayed.

I managed to create the control on a thread by making it an STA thread. Then I used the code from here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/swick/archive/2007/12/02/rendering-ink-and-image-to-a-bitmap-using-wpf.aspx to create the screenshot.

This doesn't work though: the control always has a size of 0 and therefore this crashes. Even if I specify a width and height manually it won't work, the saved image is always black.

Here's my code:

```
private void CreateScreenshotThread()
{
    var image = CreateImage();
    TakeScreenshot(image , @"e:\1.bmp");
}
```

I also tried to *UpdateLayout()* but without success. Do you have any idea how I can enforce a layout update and rendering of the control? I played around with PresentationSource but without success (don't fully understand the purpose of that class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, the bit you are missing is possibly the measure and arrange of the control:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var thread = new Thread(CreateScreenshot);
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
    }

    private void CreateScreenshot()
    {
        Canvas c = new Canvas { Width = 100, Height = 100 };
        c.Children.Add(new Rectangle { Height = 100, Width = 100, Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red) });

        var bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)c.Width, (int)c.Height, 120, 120, PixelFormats.Default);
        c.Measure(new Size((int)c.Width, (int)c.Height));
        c.Arrange(new Rect(new Size((int)c.ActualWidth, (int)c.ActualHeight)));
        bitmap.Render(c);

        var png = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        png.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap));

        using (Stream stm = File.Create("c:\\temp\\test.png"))
        {
            png.Save(stm);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Your example works - but in my code I'm using an Image and that one doesn't work: the screenshot is always white. I derived from Image and overrode OnRender to see if that one is called - and indeed it is (callstack starts from the Arrange()-call).

Comment: I'm sorry, it was my mistake - the Image that I loaded wasn't copied to the output directory and I thought it would be loaded from the assembly itself (the file was marked as "Resource"). Thus, the image couldn't be loaded.